# py.test terminates without completing with a terminal %

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest for the first time, mostly it is great, but sometimes it just terminates without completing, with no error message.

```
=========================================================================================== test session starts ============================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.1, pytest-2.8.5, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /Users/dacre/mike_tools/python, inifile:
collected 7 items

test_pipeline.py ......F%
```

Comment: I have a situation that I *think* may be this, but I don't know enough about how to troubleshoot it to ascertain it's the same problem. How could I tell whether this might be happening if I'm testing someone else's code, i.e. I'd rather not have to dig through all of it? [Excruciating detail](https://markdownshare.com/view/21a0a63c-66bf-4fa5-91d1-7d3d0c283bc7) documented here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was in the process of posting this question, I figured it out, but I am posting it here for anyone else with the same issue.

The issue is if your code calls `close()` on `sys.stderr` or `sys.stdout` by accident. This happened to me because I had a logging function that attempted to distinguish sys.stderr from a different filehandle by the `.name` attribute. `py.test` takes control of `sys.stderr` and remaps it to a `_pytest.capture.EncodedFile` object. My function thus misinterpreted it, and called `close()` on that object. This caused premature termination with no errors.

I just rewrote my code to avoid this problem, however an alternative option would be to import modules from sys, and then test for 'pytest' in modules:

```
from sys import modules
if 'pytest' in modules:
    do something...
```